# How can I make swagger pick up api definition yaml file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springfox

I tried using this approach

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider(InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider defaultResourcesProvider) {
        return () -> {
            SwaggerResource wsResource = new SwaggerResource();
            wsResource.setName("Documentation");
            wsResource.setSwaggerVersion("3.0");
            wsResource.setLocation("/swagger.yaml");

            List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>(defaultResourcesProvider.get());
            resources.add(wsResource);
            return resources;
        };
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to work, the file isn't picked up from resources directory.
Any suggestions?

Comment: And it does work for `"/swagger.json"`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, see for instance: https://songrgg.github.io/operation/host-swagger-documentation-with-yaml-json-files/.

Most likely you have `swagger.yaml` located in a different directory than your SwaggerConfiguration, so check if `/swagger.yaml` shouldn't be `<relative-path>/swagger.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer finally. My problem was in the fact that I had @EnableWebMvc annotation on one of the config classes.
The annotation breaks all spring-boot auto configuration for static resources (standard classpathes where all static resources picked up automatically).